# Spring JPA repository locking confusion

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

I have some confusion on the way the locking on Spring JPA repository works and needs some clarification on same.

So, I have a Spring boot service in which i am using hibernate to interact with database.
In one of the service i have an Entity like this :-

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="JUNIPER_SCH_CURRENT_JOB_DETAIL", schema="juniperx")
    public class JuniperSchCurrentJobDetail {

    private int currentJobSequence;

        ......

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="CURRENT_JOB_SEQUENCE")
    public int getCurrentJobSequence() {
    return currentJobSequence;
    }
    public void setCurrentJobSequence(int currentJobSequence) {
    this.currentJobSequence = currentJobSequence;
    }
    .......
```

Now i have a repository on top of this marked as @Repository and extending JPARepository as below :

```
   @Repository
   public interface JuniperSchCurrentJobDetailRepository extends 
   JpaRepository<JuniperSchCurrentJobDetail, String> {

   @Query
   public List<Object[]> findLastRunJobDetail(@Param("projectId") 
    String projectId);
```

So the confusion is that one of my colleague told me not to use @Repository and @Entity for this table as the table being referred to has very high rate of inserts and updates from other application. And using JPA repository will lock this table and cause issue.

So my query is :-

1) In this microservice i am using only select queries on this table, So will the select query also lock this table?

2) From what i read if i use optimistic lock it will enable a lock only when committing a transaction but since this microservice is only reading the data will it still effect other services which are making inserts and updates in this table?

3) In case the locking part is true is there anyway to stop the locking?

4) I am ok with reading dirty data in this microservice as it is for populating a dashboard which is not realtime, So is it ok to continue using @repository or should i change it to JDBC template to avoid locking problem?

5) Will annotating the class with @NoRepositoryBean and creating a read only repository help?

Comment: You don't need the `@Repository` annotation on the repository interface.

Comment: How will that help? Sorry but needed a bit insight.
Also will that solve the locking issue?

Comment: It won't help. The annotation is just completely redundant. That's why I made it a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the select query also lock this table?
>
> this microservice is only reading the data will it still effect other services which are making inserts and updates in this table?

Some databases will create locks on tables when reading from them.

This however is completely independent from JPA and highly database specific.
You'd need to look into the specific database you are using to learn how it behaves.

Writes will generally create locks, at least for the row you are writing, but also for rows that get referenced via foreign keys.
Some database might lock more rows than they actually write to.

Again this is true if you use JPA, JDBC or any SQL tool of your choice.

> From what i read if i use optimistic lock it will enable a lock only when committing a transaction

No, optimistic locking won't create any additional (blocking) locks beyond the ones mentioned above.
It might though make updates fail when between reading and writing a row another update happened.
Actually the purpose of optimistic locking is to prevent lost updates without blocking writes (and possibly reads).

In summary I don't see how JPA would in its default configuration would generate more locks than using something more low level like the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: So this should not affect other application doing inserts and updates just because i am using JPARepository....?